# Create custom entrypoint without entity

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

With Api-Platform, exposing Doctrine Entities is quite easy and works very well but I don't see how to create custom entrypoint without entities just to call an external service and get its data or do complex treatments

I saw this post ([API Platform - Which approach should I use for creating custom operation without entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58398351/api-platform-which-approach-should-i-use-for-creating-custom-operation-without)) but I don't want to create a POST method just to insert my logic in a data persister.

If i just want to create one entrypoint `/getMyCustomData` with the `GET` method and without passing any parameter, what should I do?

I looked at swagger decorators but if I understand, it works on an existing entity.

Comment: Why do you need Api-Platform for this?

Comment: Api platform helps me for CRUD of a lot of entities but to keep the API documentation up to date, i want this entrypoint to be documented in the swagger documentation. Like Mattin answered, i can create a controller but doing so don't add the entrypoint in the swagger documentation.
and i didn't found a Action-Domain-Responder example if it is the rigth solution to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create just a normal controller in Symfony.

```
/**
 * @Route("/getMyCustomData", methods={"GET"}, name="my_api_custom_data")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function getMyCustomDataAction(Request $request): Response
{

   /** your code **/

}
```

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers => Note: using custom controllers with API Platform is discouraged.
And doing this don't add the route in the swagger documentation of the API

Comment: It's not discouraged. As you can see I used action class as mention in documentation you posted. Still, there's no other way of doing this, than creating your custom controller. Only side-effect is that this endpoint is not in swagger/openapi documentation, but you can add it manually if you need this. Btw for API documentation/testing/mockaping I recommend using postman or apiary... You just get openapi export from api-platform, put it there and add your custom routes as well (everything can by automated during CI).

Comment: Btw to have clear implementation of api-paltform. You can put a prefix for it, like api.myapi.com/api so all api-platform endpoints are after this prefix, and then for custom endpoint you can use api.myapi.com/getMyCustomData or use prefix as well. I'm using api-platform just for crud and react-admin, but backend is used for mobile app as well and they're using other routes, everything works very well together :).

Comment: And as I mentioned you can override swagger/openApi spec (for adding your custom endpoints). See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/swagger/#overriding-the-openapi-specification

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I finally did a you said and create a swagger decorator.

Comment: @Mattin Where can I find a complete example of a POST action using the decorator approach? I cant seem to make it right, I am having trouble to do the example body request